# Python how to count the nested list of lists containing strings

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, arraylist

I have a nested lists of list. I want to know total items in the main and sublists. Then accordingly I want to choose a value for each sublist or item.

My code:

```
y = ['ab',['bc','cd'],'ef']
print([len(y[i]) for i in range(len(y))])
alpha=0.5
plot_alpha = [alpha for i in range(len(y)) if len(y[i])>1 else 0.5]
print(plot_alpha)
```

My present answer:

```
[2, 2, 2]
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Expected answer:

```
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 0.5, 1]
```

Comment: You don't have a list of lists, you have a list of mixed types (strings and lists).  You need to either fix `y` so that it's actually a list of lists, or you need to adjust the rest of your code to treat a string as if it were a list containing that one string.

Comment: `len('ab')` is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if each element is a list and handle them differently.

```py
print([len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 1 for x in y]) 
# [1, 2, 1]
plot_alpha = [alpha if isinstance(x, list) else 1 for x in y]
# [1, 0.5, 1]
```

Comment: I just came to know about the `isinstance.` This is a great answer to my situation. Also, you rectified the `for` loop mistake in my answer.